# Find fy if $X$ has a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$, and let $Y = X^2$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ has a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$, and let $Y = X^2$. Find $f_Y$

Comment: Hello Anum, I see that you are asking a lot of questions recently. Please be aware that there are caps of $6$ questions per $24$ hour period, and $50$ questions per month; SE will not let you exceed these caps, so please plan accordingly. Please also include *your* thoughts and efforts in the questions: This will help people write answers appropriate to your question, and help avoid having your questions closed as off-topic.

Comment: sorry about that. i didn't know  that policy of yours

Comment: I think it is not clear about what you say? Hope you can prove it.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by $f_Y$ or $fy$.

Answer (score 3):

We are given the uniform distribution $f_X$.  We want to determine $f_Y$ where $Y = X^2$.

Hint:  First, solve for $X$.  Then, determine the cumulative distribution of $f_Y$, evaluating $P(X \leq y)$.  Finally, take the derivative of that equation to obtain the distribution.

Comment: can you please help me solving it properly please. It will be a great favour

Comment: Since this is the HW problem, users like me need to give you the hints unless you are totally stuck or you truly tried your best, but didn't get any result.

Comment: First, solve for $X$ for $Y = X^2$.  Then, express $f_X$ in terms of $y$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to NasuSama's answer / hint, consider what is happening with the domain of $Y$.  For instance, since $Y=X^2$, and $X$ is over the interval $[-1,1]$, what happens to values of $Y$ when $X=-1$?  $X=1$?

Also consider that $F(y)=P(Y\le{y})...$  Now what does $Y$ equal?